# How to add a select collection type select list to field collection

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am currently using the [field collection module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) on a site to allow an editor to create different types of content and reorder then.

I would like to add a select list to the creation of a field collection so that it works in a similar way to the [paragraph module](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) where a user creates a paragraph of a certain type and can then rearrange it on the page with the drag and drop interface.

Does any body know if there is a module that would implement this functionality?

I can get close to this by placing my field collections inside another field collection that is set to allow unlimited items, so that the editor can enter data in whichever type he requires and then add another. The problem with this is that the edit page becomes very large very quickly because of lots of empty field collections.

I would like it to look something like this image from the paragraph module

[image]

I am not using the paragraph module because i prefer the view integration that field collection provides.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for this question. Also, can you provide an example of how the edit form/article should look like?

Comment: So you are looking to add a select list to field collection or wanting to add field collections based on select list?

Comment: Hi Paul I have added an image of what I am after

Comment: Yes pal4life or if I add all of the different collections to a wrapping collection that is attached to the node I would just need the select list to hide and show the relevant input form